# Convert a Diagonal Sparse Matrix to a 1-D vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a big n-square diagonal matrix, in scipy's sparse DIA format
(let's say n = 100000)

```
D_sparse = sprs.diags(np.ones(100000),0)
```

I'd like to retrieve the diagonal as a vector (in the numpy array)

But if I do `np.diag(D_sparse.toarray())`, I get a `MemoryError` because `D_sparse.toarray()` generates a huge array quasi-full of 0.

I there a method or a function to get directly the diagonal of `D_sparse` as an numpy array?

Comment: For DIA format, the diagonals are stored in the `D_sparse.data` attribute.  And offsets in `D_sparse.offsets`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`diagonal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dia_matrix.diagonal.html) method of the `dia_matrix` object returns the main diagonal.

For example,

```
In [165]: d
Out[165]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>

In [166]: d.A
Out[166]: 
array([[ 10.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,  11.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,  12.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,  13.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  14.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  15.]])

In [167]: d.diagonal()
Out[167]: array([ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.])
```